# ubuntu log in loop - even in shell

Tags: login

My computer froze overnight whilst running an R script. The software updater 'need to restart' box had popped up and everything had crashed out. I managed to xkill/killall everything and reboot the system... but now I can't log in at all.

From the home screen it blanks out and just asks again.

From the shell it does the same thing!

It quickly spits some text at me which I grabbed a photo of - the last lines say:

```
Creating directory ''.
Unable to create and initialise directory ''.

Permission denied
```

And then it asks to log in again.

Any ideas anyone??? I can't even access a command line!

Thanks

Comment: which version of Ubuntu do you use? Can you reach at display manager `lightdm`?

Comment: Sounds like an error in a log script to me, but gui login can fail due to insufficient space (but you don't usually see any messages just returned to greeter). Your release/flavor may provide more clues (instead of us guessing)